# How would I make a function in r work with any number of input

Tags: r

The function I made does the prediction of the first coefficient. Is there an easy way to do it for however many the input gives you, or would I have to do a bunch of if else statements about the length of the vector coefficients.

```
fitted_line <- function(coeff, father){
  coeff[1] + coeff[2]*father
}
fit_2<- lm(Strength ~  Cement + Superplasticizer + Age + Water, data = concrete)
fitted_line(fit_2$coefficients, 250)
```

Comment: Please give an example for another input. What do you expect? What is the function going to do with 4 coefficients?

Comment: If it had 4 coefficients it would calculate the answer by doing coeff[1] + coeff[2] * father[1]... coeff[4] * father[3]. It would be something like this the father would be user specified into a vector numbers you want. I would like to do something like this: coeff[i] + coeff[i+1] * father[i] ... coeff[n] * father[n-1]. N being the amount of coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a small change on your function:

```r
fitted_line <- function(coeff, father){
  return(sum(coeff * c(1,father)))
}
```

Note that `coeff` needs to be a vector of `length >= 2`, and `father` of `length(coeff) - 1`.

Comment: Thank you that is a much easier way than what I was thinking.

Comment: Haha will do ;)